# How to detect if image is all black using flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I'm building an app that user required to send a selfie but some user just block the camera to take a picture and the result is all black, is there a way to detect if image is black?

I'm thinking of using face detection but I haven't tried it and its way to much for my simple app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can try is using [palette_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator/install) package to extract colors in the image and then computing average luminance of the image, like so.

```
import 'package:palette_generator/palette_generator.dart';

  Future<bool> isImageBlack(ImageProvider image) async {
    final double threshold = 0.2; //<-- play around with different images and set appropriate threshold
    final double imageLuminance = await getAvgLuminance(image);
    print(imageLuminance);
    return imageLuminance < threshold;
  }

  Future<double> getAvgLuminance(ImageProvider image) async {
    final List<Color> colors = await getImagePalette(image);
    double totalLuminance = 0;
    colors.forEach((color) => totalLuminance += color.computeLuminance());
    return totalLuminance / colors.length;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before use camera check if your app has permission for that.

For this porpouse i've recommend to use the [permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

Few lines from official documentation

```
 var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    if (status.denied) {
      // We didn't ask for permission yet or the permission has been denied before but not permanently.
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm currently using permission to use the camera what I want is to identify the color of the image taken